# I cannot use rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did rails console in my terminal to check model have datas(user.name = "Yuri"&user.email = "odyssey"). However, the terminal says

```
[3] pry(main)> user = User.new
NameError: uninitialized constant User
from (pry):3:in `__pry__'
```

Is this mean models don't have any data?
I'm a beginner, so is this my mistake to use the terminal?(In that case, what should I do in the terminal ?)

In model, I wrote

```
class Userdatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  user = User.new
  user.name = "XXX"
  user.email = "mail"
  user.save
end
```

Comment: do you have User model?

Comment: @rose Please add your modal as well as you are trying to access the User that means there should be User model in app/modals/user.rb

Comment: please check this link once,  https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry

Comment: @Sravan thx.I add my model.

Comment: @VishalG thx.I add my model

Comment: Do you even have `User` model

Comment: @Rose2017 np keep it up

Comment: ＠ Deepak Mahakale What do u mean User model?It is the modal in my para ,isn't it?

Comment: @VishalG What is np?Do u think my explanation isn't enough??

Comment: @Rose2017 its no problem   change your model to `class User < ActiveRecord::Base end`  And call `user = User.new` all this stuff from pry